# Ubuntu apt-get install (--download-only) executed from another machine on behalf of mine

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I have a server on a network segment with no direct or indirect access to the Internet. I want to perform an:

```
apt-get install <package_name>
```

Is there a way to somehow delegate the process of downloading the required files to another machine by exporting the server configuration so as to satisfy all dependencies while running:

```
apt-get install --download-only <package_name>
```

Can, in effect, apt-get install read a configuration from an exported archive rather than from the local package database?

Can the list of packages to be downloaded be retrieved, along with an installation script to perform the installation, instead of the actual packages? (a further level of indirection which would help me schedule this with wget at appropriate times...)

Answer (score 1):

If there's a candidate machine, you might try [apt-proxy](http://apt-proxy.sourceforge.net/), or the aforementioned [apt-offline](http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Apt on CD is one option, though this is really for creating a repository from packages in use on another machine which isn't quite what you were wanting.  [Apt Offline](http://apt-offline.alioth.debian.org/) is another option which can be used to update your packages offline, and finally you can come up with your own solution involving the --print-uris option of apt-get and wget.